# methods of filtering and transforming for a table

Tags: j

I have a table, and want to do filtering on it. Example use cases include:

```
4 6 8 6 5
8 6 6 6 9
3 2 3 1 9
2 7 0 9 5
7 7 9 7 4
8 7 4 2 1
1 0 4 3 9
3 2 7 4 4
0 3 7 5 9
6 3 2 8 2
```

- only retain rows where second element equals 2, i.e. should return

> ```
> 3 2 3 1 9
> 3 2 7 4 4
> ```

- only retain columns where second element equals 6, i.e. should return

> ```
> 6 8 6
> 6 6 6
> 2 3 1
> 7 0 9
> 7 9 7
> 7 4 2
> 0 4 3
> 2 7 4
> 3 7 5
> 3 2 8
> ```

- return rows where the sum of first and second element equals 9

> ```
> 2 7 0 9 5
> 6 3 2 8 2
> ```

- transform the table into a new table, where first column is the sum of first and second columns in the original table, and second column is the difference between the third and the first columns, i.e.

> ```
>    10    4
>    14   _2
>     5    0
>     9   _2
>    14    2
>    15   _4
>     1    3
>     5    4
>     3    7
>     9   _4
> ```

- transform the table into a new table, where first row is the sum of first and second rows in the original table, and second row is the difference between the third and the first rows, i.e.

> 12   12   14   12   14
>      _1   _4   _5   _5    4

Comment: Your second example makes no sense.

Comment: why? what is not clear?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This stuff is in the primer. Read the primer and you will learn about primitives which will come in handy for this like `{`, `#` and `I.`.

Comment: I read the primer, but still not sure how to go about doing this sort of things.

Comment: I found this question entirely clear in both intent and exposition. That it is comprised of a series of questions makes sense because the overarching question has to do with how the common pattern varies by axis.

Comment: Example #2: "only retain columns where second element equals 6", where the answer lists (a.o.) "2 3 1" and "7 0 9".

Answer (score 1):

Selecting: `{`

Selecting rows: `{"1`

Testing: `=`

Choosing: `#`

---

#### Second element of each row

```
1 {"1 in
6 6 2 7 7 7 0 2 3 3
```

#### test if second element equals 2

```
2 = 1 {"1  in
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

#### choose rows when second element equals 2

```
( 2 = 1 {"1  in) # in   NB. or  in #~ (2=1{"1 in) or (]#~ 2 = 1 {"1 ]) in
3 2 3 1 9
3 2 7 4 4
```

#### equivalently for rows where second element equals 6

```
( 6 = 1 { in) #"1 in
6 8 6
6 6 6
2 3 1
7 0 9
7 9 7
7 4 2
0 4 3
2 7 4
3 7 5
3 2 8
```

#### sum of first and second element of rows

```
(+/"1) 0 1 {"1 in
10 14 5 9 14 15 1 5 3 9
```

#### choose rows where above sum eq. 9

```
in #~ (9 = (+/"1) 0 1 {"1 in)
2 7 0 9 5
6 3 2 8 2
```

#### additions etc

append previous results:

```
((+/"1) 0 1 {"1 in) ,. (-/"1) 0 2 {"1 in
10 _4
14  2
 5  0
 9  2
14 _2
15  4
 1 _3
 5 _4
 3 _7
 9  4
```

Comment: thank you very much. BTW, how were you able to get the input `in` into the system as a table?

Comment: `in =: ".;._2  (0 : 0) <enter><copy-paste><enter> )`: parse input text

Comment: You could, of course, enter them in one line: `in =: 10 5 $ 4 6 8 6 5
8 6 ...`

Comment: One more little request. How can I select rows where the absolute difference between the third element and the first is 4, in this case, it should return `4 6 8 6 5`, `8 7 4 2 1`, `6 3 2 8 2`, and `3 2 7 4 4`. Thanks a million.

Comment: *"choose from `in`, where 4 = absolute of difference of rows 0,2"*: `in #~ 4 = |(-/"1) 0 2 {"1 in`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33838/discussion-between-rich-and-eelvex)